# package pcre-8.32-15.el7_2.1.x86_64 (which is newer than pcre-7.8-7.el6.x86_64) is already installed

Tags: linux, apache, centos7

I am trying to install httpd-2.2.15-54.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm but is noticed:

> libpcre.so.0()(64bit) is needed by httpd-2.2.15-54.el6.centos.x86_64

then I try install pcre-7.8-7.el6.x86_64.rpm i am noticed:

> package pcre-8.32-15.el7_2.1.x86_64 (which is newer than
>   pcre-7.8-7.el6.x86_64) is already installed
>           file /usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0 from install of pcre-7.8-7.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package
>   pcre-8.32-15.el7_2.1.x86_64
>           file /usr/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0 from install of pcre-7.8-7.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package
>   pcre-8.32-15.el7_2.1.x86_64

what can I do?

ps: this machine don´t have internet, then I can not run yum :(